# Como fazer horizontal scroll com divs do tamanho do ecrã

Tags: html, css, rolamento

Eu tenho 4 `div's` que gostava de pôr um `scroll` horizontal para navegá-las mas as `div's` são do tamanho do ecrã (e quero que fiquem com o tamanho total do ecrã). Eu consegui fazer um exemplo porém como as `div's` ocupam o tamanho total do ecrã não premite fazer `scroll`, o `scroll` fica `disabled`

[Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/Gibellino/YbrX3/1742/) está o exemplo que fiz.

Comment: @BrenoCosta rejeitei sua edição pois você alterou características linguísticas do autor, que é de Portugal e esse tipo de edição não é válida no site. Recomendo a leitura [**deste tópico**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3/28595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você chegou bem perto. Lembre-se que os tamanhos com % são relativos ao pai do elemento. No seu exemplo, a classe `wrapper_child` está com 400%, até aí tudo certo, porém a definição da classe filha `tab`, `.wrapper_child > .tab`, indica que cada div terá o tamanho de 100%, ou seja, o mesmo tamanho da pai, que está com 400% da tela.

Para resolver, basicamente é dividir: 100% / 4 = 25%

Isso já acerta o tamanho. Só falta acertar agora deixar as `divs` lado a lado, ao invés de uma em cima da outra (não da pra ver pois está sem scroll vertical), e isso você consegue adicionando em `tab` o `float: left;`.

Veja como fica. Só troquei as cores pra ficar mais suave rs:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wrapper_child{
  width: 400%;
  height: inherit;
}

.wrapper_child > .tab {
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#home {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);/*yellow;*/
}

#gallery {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);/*green;*/
}

#about {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);/*blue;*/
}

#contacts {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);/*red;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper_child">
    <div id="home" class="tab">
      <h3 class="text-center align-middle">Home</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="gallery" class="tab">
      <h3 class="text-center align-middle">Gallery</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="about" class="tab">
      <h3 class="text-center align-middle">About us</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="contacts" class="tab">
      <h3 class="text-center align-middle">Contacts</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem o que deseja, é o que está nesse exemplo que fiz: [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/maxtools50/axochhrh/)

Somente modifiquei seu CSS:

```
.wrapper_child > .tab {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Você havia posto que o wrapper "pai" tem 400% do tamanho da tela. Logo os 100% do seu conteúdo representa 400% da tela. Seu filhos então que são 4 precisam ser 25% do seu espaço. Para viabilizar ficarem lado a lado coloquei ainda a propriedade CSS `display: inline-block;` para realizar esse trabalho. Coloquei também a propriedade `margin-right: -4px;` pra ajustar um espaço que havia ficado entre as `divs`.

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo que você tem, a `div` com a class `wrapper_child` tem 400% de width, ou seja, 4 vezes maior que o ecrã, por isso é que põe `scroll`. Se você pretende ter o mesmo efeito, tem que adicionar uma `width` com mais de 100%.

Comment: Eu quero mesmo o scroll. 4 div's com o tamanho do ecrã todas lado a lado.